# mongoose dynamic references based on attribute

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to have a dynamic reference based on another attribute in schema?

I have the following schemas, where location can be controlled by either a person or an organization (example a Office Building is controlled by a corporation, where as a Local Store is controlled by the owner).

```
// Has other fields - brief for simplicity.
var personSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
}); 
var PersonData = mongoose.model('PersonData', personSchema ); 


// Has other fields - brief for simplicity.
var organizationSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    members: [{ type: String, ref: 'PersonData'}]
}); 
var OrganizationData = mongoose.model('OrganizationData', organizationSchema ); 

var locationSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    controlledBy:{ 
            type: {String, enum: [ 'Organization', 'Individual']},
            controller: { type: String, ref: 'PersonData' or 'OrganizationData'}
    }
});
```

I guess one option would be to put two fields in "controlledBy" but not sure if that is the best way to do it?

```
controlledBy:{ 
    type: {String, enum: [ 'Organization', 'Individual']},
    individual: { type: String, ref: 'PersonData' },
    organization: { type: String, ref: 'OrganizationData'}
}
```

With the above I think I could maybe drop the type then?

Comment: Got a response from cross-posting. 
In looking at the documentation link you posted, I believe what  I would need in my model is as follows:

    var locationSchema = new Schema({
        _id: {type: String, required: true},
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        controlledBy:{ 
                kind: {type: String, enum: [ 'OrganizationData', 'IndividualData']},  
                controller: {type: ObjectId, refPath: 'controlledBy.kind'},
        }
    });

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/km3rBB9UidQ

Comment: If your locationSchema.controlledBy were an array, do you know how to count separately the count of Organization and the count of Individual ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I used the same solution you used.
But then, I got introduced to [Dynamic Referencing with `refPath`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref). The difference between `ref` and `refPath` is that with `refPath`, you can configure what model Mongoose uses for each document instead of the hardcoded String with `ref`.
A solution I would suggest for you would be:

```
controllerType:{ 
  type: String,
  enum: [ 'Organization', 'Individual']
},
controllerId: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  refPath: 'controllerType'
}
```